# Disable tab preview / thumbnail on bottom panel? - Ubuntu 20.04 Mate

Tags: 20.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, interface

Since the upgrade to 20.04, the version of GNOME I was using as the interface was no longer supported very well and MATE seemed the most similar to it, so that is what I have switched to.

One of the main irritating things about it though is the pop-up thumbnails for the tabs on the bottom panel. I am aware that Windows does this as well, but I’m simply not used to it. The tile already says what window it is, so I don’t really see why you also need an image (which is already overlapped by the title).

The biggest problem is that around half the time the thumbnails are not even correct. As the second picture below shows, it is just a zigzag pattern of multiple windows overlapping each other and it is very misleading. Sometimes it is just a pixelated mess. It also often shows a thumbnail of what is in fact the tab to the left or right of it. The title is correct, and that in my view is all you need.

Here is a thumbnail of a window:

[image: img_thumbnails]

Here is an example of a broken thumbnail:

[image: img_broken_thumbnail]

Is there a way of disabling the thumbnails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove the thumbnails by following these steps:

1. <kbd>right-click</kbd> on the three vertical dots right before the Firefox icon in your panel:

   [image: panel with where to click annotation]
2. Click *Preferences*.
3. In the menu that will open, select the *Hide thumbnails on hover* option and close the menu:

   [image: Window List Preferences]

Comment: Thanks for this. Also have worked out that the glitches are related to my Nvidia drivers. If I use Nouveau Open source instead of Nvidia (which doesn't work correctly for me because of my graphics card), it does however stop the window glitches. At least I can now remove them in addition to that, although that tiny menu is pretty well hidden!